# how to visualize 3d Map in RViz using Octomap?

Tags: rviz, octomap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello I am learning octomap to create 3d maps . I cloned this [link](https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap_mapping) into my system and used these steps:

1. rosbag play
2. cloned link
3. Edited launch file to change `remap <cloud_in> to <>`

   ```
        <!-- fixed map frame (set to 'map' if SLAM or localization running!) -->
        <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="odom_combined" />

        <!-- maximum range to integrate (speedup!) -->
        <param name="sensor_model/max_range" value="5.0" />

        <!-- data source to integrate (PointCloud2) -->
        <remap from="cloud_in" to="/sensor_msgs/PointCloud2" />

    </node>
   ```
4. catkin_make
5. roslaunch octomap_server octomap_mapping.launch
   It ran successfully but no output.

Now, i want to see my map created using point cloud data into Rviz.
How can i do that ?

**SOlutions tried:**

Installed rviz-plugin

```
rostopic echo /sensor_msgs/PoinCloud2
WARNING: topic [/sensor_msgs/PoinCloud2] does not appear to be published yet
```

after launching file I checked topics list

rostopic list available

```
/free_cells_vis_array
/occupied_cells_vis_array
/octomap_binary
/octomap_full
/octomap_point_cloud_centers
/octomap_server/parameter_descriptions
/octomap_server/parameter_updates
/projected_map
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/sensor_msgs/PointCloud2
/tf
/tf_static
```

in my launch file I remapped cloud_in to `/octomap_point_cloud_centers` then also it was not working
then I tried `/sensor_msgs/PointCloud2`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271044/how-to-visualize-3d-map-in-rviz-using-octomap-?/) by [Eyshika](https://answers.ros.org/users/31786/eyshika/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

you need to install the octomap plugin for RViz. Here is the [link](http://wiki.ros.org/octomap_rviz_plugins).

---

Originally posted by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) with karma: 826 on 2017-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eyshika](https://answers.ros.org/users/31786/eyshika/) on 2017-09-19**:
I tried to clone this rviz code into my folder but it didnt work do I need to launch both separately ? or should i add this code in same directory ?

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-09-20**:
You don't need to do it manually. Just install the package using `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-octomap-rviz-plugins` (for kinetic).

**Comment by [Eyshika](https://answers.ros.org/users/31786/eyshika/) on 2017-09-20**:
Do I need to install octomap-server too for launching octomap_mapping or the steps I need are correct I mean cloning octomap_server ?

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-09-20**:
I think you don't need to install it. It's just another ROS package so build it with `catkin_make` command although I'm not sure about that. But if you're not planning to edit their code it's easier to just install it with `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-octomap ros-kinetic-octomap-mapping`.

**Comment by [Eyshika](https://answers.ros.org/users/31786/eyshika/) on 2017-09-23**:
Hi ! I installed octomap-mapping and also octomap-rviz-plugin, but still after launching octomap_mapping file it doesn't show any output. what is the reason behind this ? How can i see map ?

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-09-24**:
Can you edit your question and give us your .launch file? Also check your topic using `rostopic echo` if there's some data or not.

**Comment by [Eyshika](https://answers.ros.org/users/31786/eyshika/) on 2017-09-24**:
I have updated my question with launch file and `rostopic echo`

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-09-25**:
Have you checked if your pointcloud is published to `/sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` topic? Also try to increase the range of your sensor, maybe there's no obstacle within 5m.

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-09-25**:
Also check with RVIZ if you have frame named `odom_combined`. This is the default frame but I'm not sure if it's published. If you can't see `odom_combined` frame change it to e.g. `world` or your other frame.

**Comment by [Eyshika](https://answers.ros.org/users/31786/eyshika/) on 2017-09-25**:
How can I check if my point cloud is published to `/sensor_msgs/PointCloud 2` or not ? Do I need to write tf broadcaster for this , because when I opened rviz separately it shoed no tf data available ? I did open octomap display in Rviz, now how do I check the frames ?

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-09-25**:
You can check the topic with `rostopic echo /sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` command. For the frames either run `rosrun tf view_frames` which will save the tf tree to `frames.pdf`. Or in RViz there's **fixed frame** option in global options. Try to find some available frame there.

**Comment by [Eyshika](https://answers.ros.org/users/31786/eyshika/) on 2017-10-08**:
I did check it's showing nothing. If this is not the right topic then how will I know which topic I should use.

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-10-09**:
How do you generate your pointcloud? Can you see your pointcloud in RVIZ (I guess not because there's not one being published)? You need to publish pointcloud to `octomap_server` to be able to create octomap from it.